# Selling real-world goods from an iphone App?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Amazon App does it and Fandango seems to as well, but did anyone tried to provide purchase of real-world goods (books, food, etc) from an iphone App ?

Another post is mentioning PayPal API as technically possible although very likely to be rejected by apple. 
In-App purchasing clearly states against selling real goods using this mechanism.

Another option i'm looking at is filling a basket from within the app and redirecting to a web page in mobile safari for payment.

Has anyone managed to implement this type of process, and get it accepted by Apple ?

Comment: Have you been able to find some pointers to your question? We are planning on developing an app for an ecommerce site, but fear that the app might be rejected by Apple. Which of the options you have listed seems more viable?

Comment: Hi, the project for which i asked this question took some delay, so I still don't have a definitive answer on that.
I do came to think that the fact of selling real-world goods shouldn't be a problem, but the way to accept payment still is.
I would be interested in knowing a good, standard way of doing payment from within an Iphone App, but I guess that's another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eBay have an app too, they'll be using paypal, so Apple can't reject an app for using paypal.

Also, there have been a few apps (in the UK) that sell food, and other commodities, namely the Ocado app (Thanks for the spelling correction, Graham), and another which I forget the name of, that allows you to purchase flowers, chocolate, fast food, etc.